# What license should mention in footer as website theme provider

Tags: copyright, hyperlink, footer

I have a Website, i design themes for WordPress, Blogger etc for sell. 
What **license** i should mention in my site footer as website theme provider for copyright?

Answer (score 2):

A little subjective but generally for copyrighting you will use the copyright, or symbol with the company name.

*Below is just a few examples to put you in the right direction:*

- © 2017 Company Name All Rights Reserved
- © 2017 Company Name
- © Company Name
- © 2017 Company Name or its affiliated companies. All rights reserved.
- Copyright © 2017 Company Name. All Rights Reserved.
- Copyright Company Name
- The material on this site may not be reproduced, distributed, transmitted, cached or otherwise used, except with the prior written permission of Company Name.

Comment: I asked for license, Example: licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 : https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/  What should be my license link following my product.

Comment: You didn't say a particular license you wanted to use. Since the question was already a little subjective and now obviously unclear the question has been put on hold. Licenses will normally have suggested [***examples***](https://creativecommons.org/choose/results-one?license_code=by-sa&amp;jurisdiction=&amp;version=3.0&amp;lang=en). You may be able to save the question by editing and making it it less subjective and more specific. Broad, Unclear and Opinionated questions are considered off-topic on Pro Webmasters. You can find further help in our help centre and meta.

Comment: You unable to understand, that's your fault.